# Python Tkinter SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk

import Tkinter



master = Tk()

Lb1 = Listbox(master)
Lb1.insert(1, "Porshe-P9X1")
Lb1.insert(2, "Porshe-MACAN")
Lb1.insert(3, "Porshe-Facelift")
Lb1.insert(4, "Porshe-Reserved")

w = ttk.Combobox(master, values = Paramesh , ramesh)

Lb1.pack()
w.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

I am getting the error while executing the above mentioned code. can anyone explain me why it is throwing the error?

Comment: & what is the error,if i may ask?

Comment: you'd better google with the error code `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg` first next time ;)

Comment: Why are you importing Tkinter 3 different ways?

Comment: Post the error which you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

```
ttk.Combobox(master, values = Paramesh , ramesh)
```

All the named key-value paired parameters should follow normal parameters, like this

```
ttk.Combobox(master, "ramesh", values = "Paramesh")
```

Or if you wanted to pass both the names as values, you should be preparing a list here

```
ttk.Combobox(master, values = ["Paramesh", "ramesh"])
```

**Edit:** As [falsetru commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032479/python-tkinter-syntaxerror-non-keyword-arg-after-keyword-arg/22032515?noredirect=1#comment33401687_22032515) in the answer, you are importing both `Tkinter` (Python 2.x), `tkinter` (Python 3.x).

Comment: Another problem: OP is importing both `Tkinter` (Python 2.x), `tkinter` (Python 3.x). (+ `ttk` is a top-level module in Python 2.x, a submodule of `tkinter` in Python 3.x)

Comment: In addition to that, according to `ttk.Combobox` docstring, it accepts only one positional argument (`master`). [Here's a working example.](http://pastebin.com/dLtnxQgN)

Comment: @falsetru You should have posted that as a separate answer :) After looking at that example, I believe the edited answer would be what he is trying to do, because the strings in the list are Indian names :)